# Intuition: Affine map vs Linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, affine-geometry

In my Geometry course, we defined "affine map" by saying it's a map $T$ of the form $T(\mathbf{x}) =  L(\mathbf{x})+\mathbf{b}$, where $L$ is a linear map. So an affine map is just a linear map with a translation by $T(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{b}$.

Questions:

1. Is any map that preserves collinearity (ie. it maps a line to a line) affine?
2. If it's just a linear map with a translation, why bother studying it as a separate object? Instead of focusing all our attention on general linear maps.

Comment: 2. Why? Because it is more interesting and more complicated than linear maps. See for example the [affine group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group), which is the group of all invertible affine mappings. You could also ask, why to consider integers, if every integer is a product of prime powers. So why bother studying integers as a separate object?

Comment: @fweth Do you mean there are maps that map a line to a line but are **not** affine?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment, it was BS.

Comment: You can embed an affine space into a linear one by adding a dimension so it reduces to studying linear spaces anyway. You can think of it as padding the system of equations with something like $z=1$ where $z$ isn't used anywhere else as a variable then turning the equation $ax+b$ into the equation $ax+bz$ so that it's linear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A follow-up question: Since affine map preserves the relation points on a line, it should be some kind of homomorphism, what kind of homomorphism is affine map?

Comment: @EricChan the problem with affine spaces is they lack a well-defined origin so you don't really have point to map the kernel onto like you do in linear spaces.

Comment: @CyclotomicField But the OP asks rather for affine maps, not affine spaces. And invertible affine maps form a group, so this is still useful.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yeah my point is merely that the maps themselves aren't homomorphisms unless $b=0$. You can certainly think of linear maps as affine maps modulo translations which has an obvious homomorphism attached to it.

Comment: You definitely have maps from $\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{R}$ which map lines to lines (trivial) but are not affine.  Also you have maps from $\mathbf{R}$ to $\mathbf{R}^n$, like $\mapsto (x^2,0,...,0)$, which map lines to lines but are not affine.

Answer (score 2):

> Is any map that preserves collinearity (ie. it maps a line to a line) affine?

No, not every [collineation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation) is an affine transformation.

According to the [fundamental theorem of projective geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation#Fundamental_theorem_of_projective_geometry), every collineation is a combination of a [*projective* transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography) and an [automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism) of the underlying field. If the underlying field is the real numbers, then there is no non-trivial automorphism so every collineation over the reals is a projective transformation.

Projective transformations in general don't have to preserve parallelism. They form a larger class of transformations than the affine transformations. Every projective transformation that preserves parallel lines is an affine transformation.

Also, projective transformations are typically expressed as linear transformations with one more dimension, acting on [homogeneous coordinate vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates).

One potential caveat is that the concept of a collineation is typically expressed for a projective plane, which in addition to the usual lines has one extra line, the line at infinity. Affine transformations leave the line at infinity invariant. Other projective transformations map a finite line to the line at infinity. If you restrict your view to the affine plane, then you could say that such a transformation does not really map lines to lines, because there is one line that doesn't get mapped to a line of the affine plane. If you take this stance and only consider transformations which map all lines of the affine plane to lines of the affine plane, without even a single exception and without allowing for the existence of a line at infinity, and if your affine plane is over the real numbers, then yes, those transformations would all be affine transformations.

> If it's just a linear map with a translation, why bother studying it as a separate object? Instead of focusing all our attention on general linear maps.

If you have a wider class of transformations, you can use them to describe a wider range of operations that might have practical relevance for the field you study. If for example you are doing some animation, then being able to move things around would be very important. I don't see how a study of linear transformations could be a substitute for that.

Comment: So is the answer to the first question "yes" for vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, but "no" for $\mathbb{C}^n$? (since complex conjugation is an automorphism)

Comment: @paperskilltrees Since OP alles about affine transformation not projective transformation, the answer is no for any field. But for projective transformation the answer would be yes for real and no for complex numbers.

Comment: @MvG Thanks a lot for your detailed reply! May I ask a follow-up question: Is there a collineation in Euclidean space that is not affine?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 2, here is an example which I hope will be sufficiently telling.

In vector space $E=\mathbb{R}^2$ :
Let $O=(0,0), {\color{green}{O_1=(6,3)}}, s_O:E\to E, (x,y)\mapsto (-x,-y)$ and $s_{{\color{green}{O_1}}}:(x,y)\mapsto (12-x,6-y)$. Then, $s_{{\color{green}{O_1}}}s_O=t_{2{\color{red}b}}$, with ${\color{red}b}=O_1-O=(6,3)$. $s_O$ is is a well-known linear map; $s_{O_1}$ is an affine map ($s_{O_1}=t_{2b}s_O$).

[image]